# Sweet Alert confirm

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, sweetalert

Bien, tengo un problema... estoy usando `sweetalert.js` y llevo rompiendome la cabeza para entender como funciona el `confirm`

```
swal("Are you sure?", {
    dangerMode: true,
    buttons: true,
});
```

Tengo un boton `delete` y lo que quiero es que primero pregunte si se desea o no eliminar el registro, y dependiendo de que boton seleccione lo haga o no. Pero no se como hacerlo. Me lei la documentacion pero no lo explica.

En `sweetalert2` tienen una funcion de confirm mas intuitiva...

```
 Swal.fire({
 title: 'Do you want to save the changes?',
 showDenyButton: true,
 showCancelButton: true,
 confirmButtonText: 'Save',
denyButtonText: `Don't save`,
}).then((result) => {
 /* Read more about isConfirmed, isDenied below */

 if (result.isConfirmed) {

    (AQUI IRIA MI FUNCION ELIMINAR)
    
 } else if (result.isDenied) {
       
    (AQUI UNA ALERTA "TU REGISTRO ESTA A SALVO")

    }
 })
```

Pero no se como hacer eso con el `sweetalert.js` ayuda

Comment: Y donde está tu registro a eliminar? Agrega esa función o esa parte del código

Comment: Ya esta mas especificado, el problema es que en `sweetalert_1` (por decirle asi) no esta claro donde debe ir mi funcion `eliminar` en la version `sweetalert_2` si lo especifica mas claro. Quiero seguir usando la primera version, pero si no se puede tendre que usar la dos. Creo que es mas facil...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sacado de la [documentación](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#advanced-examples):

Es prácticamente idéntico a sweetalert2, le defines el callback usando `then`

```js
    swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
    icon: "warning",
    buttons: true,
    dangerMode: true,
 })
  .then((willDelete) => {
    if (willDelete) {
      swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
        icon: "success",
      });
    } else {
      swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Así con raw javascript, pero bien podrías utilizar funciones de flecha como te ha dicho Israel.

```
swal({
    title: "Your title",
    text: "Do you want to save the changes?",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: "Yes",
    confirmButtonClass: "btn-warning",
    cancelButtonText: "No",
    cancelButtonClass: "btn-danger"
},
function(isConfirm) {
    if (isConfirm) {
        /* (AQUI IRIA MI FUNCION ELIMINAR) */
    } else {
        /* AQUI UNA ALERTA "TU REGISTRO ESTA A SALVO" */
    }
});
```